# Trouble with command `git rm -r --cached /.idea`

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

In my case I have new project. Developer before me commit all files in git (with build folder, .idea folder etc). I create .gitignore and now I want delete autogeneric and system files. Earlier I do same in 3 step:
1) remove all autogeneric and system files in repository; commit and push on git.
2) create and fill .gitignore; commit and push
3) restore removed file (ussually via IDEA recreate project from gradle.build)

Now I try new way without deleting files from repository:
1) create .gitignore
2) use commands: git rm -r --cached .gitignore, git rm -r --cached /.idea; etc
3) after that I going to commit and push.
4) use command: git add . and commit and push again

But I have trouble with command `git rm -r --cached /.idea`

```
fatal: /.idea: '/.idea' is outside repository
```

Help me fix this problem=)

Comment: Just `/.idea` is folder `.idea` in the **root**. What you meant is `./.idea` Note dot before slash

Comment: 8 years later, but thank you) I spent enormous amount of time to realize what happened here and how to fix it. And of course I ignored the simplest solution))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `git rm -r --cached ./.idea`.

Note the `/` in `/.idea`: this will look up in the root filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I find easier way=)

```
git rm -r --cached . 
 git add .
 git commit -m 'Removed all files that are in the .gitignore' 
 git push origin master
```